# Redirect using routing in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have ***ASP.NET MVC*** application.
I want my application to redirect from

> example.com/Register

to

> example.com/Account/Register

How can I do it with routes? It makes little sense to me to make controller only for this one task

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [Phil Haack's RouteMagic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx/) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a redirect. You need a custom route

Add this route first (above "Default")

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Register",
                    "Register",
                    new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" }
                );
```

This solution will leave the user on URL `example.com/Register`, but instantiate Controller Account, execute ActionResult Register, and return View Account/Register.